# Java: pass int[3] to function expecting 3 int

Tags: java, arrays

From my Perl days, I'd like to be able to write code like this, given the definition [Color.rgb(int,int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html):

```
int[] myColorData = {127, 42, 251};
Color myColor = Color.rgb(myColorData);
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Java? I'm trying to avoid the verbosity of having to specify `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` and the variable name 3 times since it adds nothing to the reader.

Note that this is just a simple example; I'm interested in a more general solution and not just how to call `Color.rgb()`. I understand the type `int[]` is not the same as the type `int`, but I wonder if there is a way to decompose the array into `int`, or if there is some other calling method that would do something similar?

Comment: `Color(int rgb)` : Creates an opaque RGB color with the specified combined RGB value consisting of the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

Comment: You could write your own helper method that takes in the `int[]` and returns an (optional) `Color`. You will, however, be far better off embracing a more strongly-typed & "java-like" approach, rather than holding on to a Perl mentality...

Comment: @nullpointer - I didn't see that in the OP's text or link . Both do show `Color(int,int,int)`.

Comment: I am interested in the Java approach to this. But using Color.rgb(myColorData[0], myColorData[1], myColorData[2]) is error prone so I wonder what else I could do to store the RGB values easily yet still create a Color in a readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist that you only want to mention the variable `myColorData` once (instead of 3 times), then you can do it through reflection - but it is incredibly ugly:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
try {
    // Setup code
    Method m = Color.class.getMethod("rgb", int.class, int.class, int.class);

    // Your code
    Object[] myColorData = {127, 42, 251};
    Color myColor = (Color)m.invoke(null, myColorData);  // Invoke static method with an array of arguments

    // Confirmation
    System.out.println(myColor);

    // OMG this hurts
} catch (IllegalAccessException|IllegalArgumentException|InvocationTargetException|NoSuchMethodException|SecurityException e) {}
```

In light of this, if you see yourself using this pattern often, then it's best to write a helper method without using reflection:

```
static Color rgbColor(int[] rgb) {
    return Color.rgb(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
}
```

---

As a side note, what you want to do is easy in Python and JavaScript (assuming that an equivalent library exists):

```
# Python
myColorData = [127, 42, 251]
myColor = Color.rgb(*myColorData)

// JavaScript
var myColorData = [127, 42, 251];
var myColor = Color.rgb.apply(null, myColorData);
```

Scripting languages, unlike statically typed compiled languages, typically make it easy to invoke functions dynamically with arrays.

Comment: barring a surprise answer, I think you've answered my question. given the strongly typed nature of languages like java, there is no similar way to pass arguments lazily.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is:

```
int[] myColorData = {127, 42, 251};
Color myColor = Color.rgb(myColorData[0], myColorData[1], myColorData[2]);
```

Comment: Well, you could do it with reflection... but yes, you've described the only *sane* way ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I have aslmot no experience with reflection .. sooo let's keep *sane* as you have said in this case >,<

Answer (score 0):

> but I wonder if there is a way to decompose the array into int, or if there is some other calling method that would do something similar?

There is no direct way in Java, but you can always create your own method:

```
int[] myColorData = {127, 42, 251};
Color c = convertRGB(myColorData);

public static Color convertRGB (int[] color){
    return new Color(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
}
```

You can also write it into your own Utilities class so that you have a stash of self defined methods to use:

```
final class MyColorUtil
{
    public static Color convertRGB (int[] color){
        return new Color(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    }
}
```